# Accessing $vuetify instance property from vuex store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I was using `vuetify` and wanted to change theme from `vuex` store using [$vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/style/theme) instance but i got this error `Cannot set property 'theme' of undefined"`

here is my code

```
export default {
  getters: {},
  mutations: {
    toggleDarkTheme(state) {
      this.$vuetify.theme.primary = "#424242";
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> $vuetify is an **[instance property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html)** hence you can access any vue
> instance property using

```
Vue.prototype.$prop
```

For your case

```
import Vue from 'vue';
export default {
  getters: {},
  mutations: {
    toggleDarkTheme(state) {
      Vue.prototype.$vuetify.theme.primary = "#424242";
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Not woking with `Vue.prototype.$vuetify.lang.t()` in getters and state

Answer (score 13):

For **Vuetify 2.0** you can try following method. *(After following Vuetify 2.0 [Upgrade guide](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/releases/tag/v2.0.0#user-content-upgrade-guide) for themes)*

```
import Vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'

export default {
  getters: {},
  mutations: {
    toggleDarkTheme(state) {
      Vuetify.framework.theme.themes.light.primary = "#424242";
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 8):

This one worked for me

```
...
toggleDarkTheme(state) {
   window.$nuxt.$root.$vuetify.theme.dark = true
}
```

Comment: I can confirm, this saved me! Thanks dude!

Comment: saved me too !!

Comment: also works as `window.$nuxt.$vuetify.theme.dark`

Comment: Or replace window with globalThis

Answer (score 7):

For Nuxt.js projects with Vuetify set as a `buildModule`, you can access `$vuetify` from the `$nuxt` property in the Vue instance:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
export actions = {
  yourAction() {
    Vue.prototype.$nuxt.$vuetify.theme.dark = true;
  }
}
```