# Access vue or vuetify instance inside vuex store or getters

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

I am trying to access `$vuetify` instance from inside the vuex store or getters to translate strings that are in my static categories array. The problem is that `this` **is** `undefined` inside the `getters` and `store`.

How should I pass my app instance to store?

Note that I did try couple answers from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51106931/accessing-vuetify-instance-property-from-vuex-store) question but they all do it inside vuex `actions`. And inside the `actions` `this` **is not** `undefined`

Is my only option to make a function that just returns an array? If it is possible it would good to avoid it 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This feels like an XY problem. Why do you need access to a Vue or Vuetify instance in the store? The store should be component agnostic.

Comment: @Terry I am trying to access `$vuetify` to translate my string in static categories array. And the categories array is in state because I am using it in multiple views. And to be honest, I do not think it really is XY problem.

Comment: If that’s the case all you need is to store the locale in the store. The component itself should handle the i18n.

Comment: @Terry Okay, I can actually try it yes. Thank you for that suggestion. Thank you.